# ArrayStoreException thrown when converting HashSet to array

Tags: java, set, hashset

I have code that looks like this:

```
    int[] ho = new int[10];
    ho[0]= 1;
    ho[2]= 1;
    ho[4]= 5;

    HashSet<Integer> hs = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(ho));

    Integer[] a = hs.toArray(new Integer[hs.size()]);
```

This code makes perfect sense to me, but it throws an `ArrayStoreException` when I run it. Why is that? The `HashSet` is a set of `Integer`s, and so is the output array.

Answer (score 3):

`ArrayStoreException`: "if the runtime type of the specified array is not a supertype of the runtime type of every element in this set"

`ArrayStoreException` is thrown to indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong type of object into an array of objects.

Try switching `int[] to Integer[]`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are skipping generic types so you don't see the error and Java is not able to reject your code even if it's wrong.

The problem is that the signature of `Arrays::asList` is `asList(T... values)`, but `T` can't be a primitive so the variadic arguments are collapsed into an `int[]` (which is now an object) and `Arrays.asList` returns a `List<int[]>`.

Then pass it to a generic `HashSet` constructor which then accepts a `Collection<Object>` without any problem, and assign it to an `HashSet<Integer>`, with the compiler warning you about using raw types.

Finally you try to assign the elements in the hash set (which are of type `int[]`) to elements in an `Integer[]` array causing the exception, that's like doing

```
Integer[] data = new Integer[5];
data[0] = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
```

which is wrong but Java can't realize it at compile time.

If you had constructed the `HashSet` through `new HashSet<>` then Java compiler would have risen an error. You can solve the issue by passing an `Integer[]` to `asList` method such that it's correctly treated as variadic arguments.