# Stream.filter() leaves nulls in the array

Tags: java, java-stream

I have code like this

```
int[] array = {1, -1, 2, 3, -4};

Integer[] out = Arrays
    .stream(array)
    .filter(elem -> elem >= 0) // remove negatives
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .toArray(new Integer[array.length]);
```

But the filter operation leaves the negative elements in the array as `null`s. Why doesn't it remove them?

Comment: seems like you've been mixing `int` with `Integer` mostly -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42685825/arraystoreexception-thrown-when-converting-hashset-to-array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `out` array is the same length as `array` array.

Do either this:

```
int[] out = Arrays
        .stream(array)
        .filter(elem -> elem >= 0) // remove negatives
        .toArray();
```

or do this:

```
Integer[] out = Arrays
        .stream(array)
        .filter(elem -> elem >= 0) // remove negatives
        .boxed()
        .toArray(Integer[]::new);
```